# Is it possible to return a const statement from a function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So if I wanted to stop writing many const statements for a simple repeatable thing, should it be possible to create a function or generator or something that would let me write each statement on one line?

Example constant:

```
const bgColor = theme('mode', {
  default: light.backgroundColor,
  dark: dark.backgroundColor,
});

const textColor = theme('mode', {
  default: light.color,
  dark: dark.color,
});

const shadowColor = theme('mode', {
  default: light.boxShadowColor,
  dark: dark.boxShadowColor,
});
```

Example desired statement:

```
themeProperty('bgColor', backgroundColor);
themeProperty('textColor', color);
themeProperty('shadowColor', boxShadowColor);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't tell what you're asking or how the two code examples are related. Are you saying you want to retrieve all the `backgroundColor` properties of each `property` in the `bgColor` object? Please plainly describe what you want.

Comment: I think @ftor got to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: How so? What are the constants you're talking about? You can certainly pass or return the *value* of a `const`; you just can't delcare it inline because it's not an expression. Your example only uses one single `const`, and there's no indication of you passing or returning it.

Comment: Your second example seems to want to use `backgroundColor` to access a common property of a set of objects. If that's what you want, then absolutely this can be done, though with a little tweaking. Is there a reason you're refusing to give more detail?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `function themeProperty(prop) { return theme('mode', {default: light[prop], dark: dark[prop]}); const bgColor = themeProperty('backgroundColor');` ?

Comment: "*stop writing many const statements for a simple repeatable thing*" - yes, just don't use many variables for repeated things. Use a single array or object instead to store all the values. *Those* you can access programmatically and also generate dynamically.

Comment: I've updated the example with repeat `const` statements. It seems like there should be a simpler way to type this.

Comment: @stephenway Surely you can write a helper function that lets you do `const bgColor = themeProperty('backgroundColor'), textColor = themeProperty('color'), shadowColor = themeProperty('boxShadowColor');` But again, to avoid multiple `const` declarations, you have to avoid using multiple variables.

Answer (score 3):

So shortening the code seems to be the concern.

There are two things being shortened, the first is the repeated `const` declaration, which indeed *can* be eliminated by using destructuring assignment.

So let's do that first before we move on.

```
const [bgColor, textColor, shadowColor] = [
    theme('mode', {
      default: light.backgroundColor,
      dark: dark.backgroundColor,
    }),
    theme('mode', {
      default: light.color,
      dark: dark.color,
    }),
    theme('mode', {
      default: light.boxShadowColor,
      dark: dark.boxShadowColor,
    })
];
```

Of course, that's a minimal improvement, but it does eliminate the `const` being typed thrice.

---

As to the objects being passed, I don't know why `'mode'` disappeared, but I'll add it back in. What you can do is create a map of target properties to objects, and provide the common property that should be extracted for each.

```
const propObjMap = new Map([
  ["default", light],
  ["dark", dark],
]);
```

Then create a function that creates a new object from the map and property name.

```
function mToObj(map, prop) {
  const res = {};
  for (const [key, obj] of map.entries()) {
    res[key] = obj[prop];
  }
  return res;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
const [bgColor, textColor, shadowColor] = [
  theme('mode', mToObj(propObjMap, "backgroundColor")),
  theme('mode', mToObj(propObjMap, "color")),
  theme('mode', mToObj(propObjMap, "boxShadowColor")),
];
```

---

And then because there's still a bit of repetition, you can create another function that receives a list of the properties, and returns an array to destructure.

```
function themes(...props) {
  return props.map(p => theme('mode', mToObj(propObjMap, p)));
}
```

So now your `const` destructuring assignment will look like this:

```
const [bgColor, textColor, shadowColor] = themes(
  "backgroundColor", "color", "boxShadowColor"
);
```

---

The `themes` function can be made more generic by receiving the argument for `'mode'` as a parameter, as well as that of the `propObjMap` in case there are other mappings.

```
function themes(m, map, ...props) {
  return props.map(p => theme(m, mToObj(map, p)));
}
```

Making the call look like this:

```
const [bgColor, textColor, shadowColor] = themes(
  'mode',
   propObjMap,
  "backgroundColor", "color", "boxShadowColor"
);
```

Comment: Side note, if your `light` and `dark` object used symbols instead of traditional property names, then you could pass those symbols so that you eliminate the quotation marks. So a single call would be `theme('mode', mToObj(properObjMap, backgroundColor))`, assuming you created a `backgroundColor` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, it is a particular variable declaration that determines whether it is `const` or not and the `const` feature only applies to that specific declared variable, not to its contents.

So, you can't return a value from a function that is `const`.  You would have to assign it to a variable that was declared as `const`.

```
const color = themeProperty(...);
```

In this, `color` is const, not because of anything that `themeProperty()` did, but because of the declaration of the `color` variable.

If you then did:

```
const color = themeProperty(...);
let color2 = color;
```

Then, `color2` is not `const`.

Similarly, it doesn't matter what you do inside of `themeProperty()`:

```
 function themeProperty() {
     // only this particular color variable is const
     const color = 'red';
     return color;        // returning it will not make the value const
 }

 let x = themeProperty();
 let y = x;
 x = 'blue';     // allowed because x is not const
 y = 'green';    // allowed because y is not const
```

So, variables themselves are `const` as determined only by their declaration, not particular values that are assigned to other variables.

A variable's `const`-ness cannot be passed to a function or returned from a function.  The closest work-around would like be to pass in or return a frozen object (thus the object's properties could not be changed).  But, you can't "freeze" a single value that is passed in or returned.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this relates to *"I wanted to stop writing many `const` statements for a simple repeatable thing"*. Could be that destructuring assignment into a set of `const` variables is desired. And that's just one of the many possible interpretations of this remarkably vague question.

Comment: @llama - I answered the question as best I understood it and tried to be helpful and useful.  Based on the OP's second comment beneath their question, this is what I thought they were asking about.  If you want something that a function returns `const`, you have to repeat that `const` declaration every time you call the function and assign its return value into a new variable.  There is no way around that.  You can't return something from a function that is automatically `const`.